# Issue in rails 4.0 with creating a link_to for a delete action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first project in rails, which is to create a table that will store data about games. I'm able to display data from the table about winner score, loser score, etc. However, I have issues with my table column that contains delete links for each game.

Here's my code in the games controller for the delete method:

```
def delete
  @game = Game.find(params[:game])
  @game.destroy()
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

A snippet of my table code, which includes the line for the link_to command

```
    <% @games_items.each do |t| %>
     <tr>
        <td><%= t.winner.name %></td>
        <td><%= t.loser.name %></td>
        <td><%= t.challenger.name %></td>
        <td><%= t.winner_score %></td>
        <td><%= t.loser_score %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete', delete_game_path(id: t.id)%></td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
```

In the routes file I called

```
resources :games
```

Which, to my knowledge, helps generate the base routing. Could anyone help me figure out why my link_to is not working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use (which is adviced) `resources`:
a) Your action for deleting records should be named `destroy`.
b) Game is searched for with `:id` parameter:

```
def destroy
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game.destroy
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

c) Your link should be:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', t, method: :delete %>
```

since the path is the same as for the `show` action, the only thig that changes is HTTP method.

Comment: Where should I look to see what my actions should be named? Is that contained in the rake routes method?

Comment: @MichaelLiu yes, the output of `rake routes` task contains appropriate action names.

Comment: @MarekLipka I'm having the exact same problem but I can't get the `:delete` method to work. No matter what I do, it results in a `get` request. Any ideas why? `      <%= link_to("Delete!", {:controller=>'projects', :action=>'destroy', :id=>project.hashed_id}, {method: :delete} ) %>
`

Comment: @Emerson your JavaScript doesn't probably work. Check your browser's console for possible JS errors.

Answer (score 6):

The format for the delete call is:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', game_path(t.id), :method => :delete %>
```

use `rake routes` to learn about the available routes, including generated route helpers, and the controller/action handling the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is actually what i want. :)

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue on rails 4.2.1, even with the :method => :delete on link_to it still routes to show method.

But using button_to method as below works!

```
<%= button_to "delete", article_path(:id => article.id), :method => :delete %>
```

button_to creates a form around the button and then posts to the delete method, by adding a hidden field named `_method` with value `delete` rails uses this to route to the destroy method in your controller.

Comment: I had this same problem where `link_to` wasn't working with `method: :delete`, but solved it by adding `jquery_ujs` to my application.js https://stackoverflow.com/a/23331608/4249632

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` before `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in your layout, and also delete

```
//= require jquery
```

line in your application.js.
This was the case for me. No idea why it didn't worked with original rails jquery.js file.