# Rails 4 link_to Destroy not working in Getting Started tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working through the Getting Started tutorial (creating a Blog) and the link_to Destroy is not functioning properly. In the terminal it always interprets it as  #SHOW.

In reading similar issues I have learned that the Delete must be converted to a POST for the browser to interpret it. This doesn't seem to be happening.

I have run into the same problem using Destroy in the Lynda.com Rails course as well, so it leads me to believe it is something in my development environment. I am using Rails 4, Ruby 2.00p274,  MySQL, WEBrick for the HTTP server on a MacBook Pro Lion.

in the terminal session when Destroy is selected:

```
Started GET "/posts/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-09 13:45:20 -0600
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

In the ports-controller.rb:

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to action: :index
end
```

In the index.html.erb:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
     <td><%= post.text %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy',  { action: :destroy, id: post.id }, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

In the routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :posts do
     resources :comments
   end
  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: Show your layouts/application.html.erb and app/assets/application.js.

Comment: You have to use the `jquery_ujs` library included by default in a new Rails application to make `:delete` methods POST to the endpoint as expected.

Comment: @ssorallen: Post that as an answer! I had exactly the same problem, and the answers given yet do not help, but including jquery_ujs into the file `application.js` did solve it for me. Perhaps only a problem when you migrate ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete link sends "Get" instead of "Delete" in Rails 3 view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view)

Answer (score 56):

Try this

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy',  post,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: How do you expect this to help?

Comment: As I said - try! I didt said that this is 100 % answer . It very hard to conclude from the information given.

Comment: Maybe author should check his browser. I think JavaScript is turned off. Or switch to another.

Comment: But it definitely is a bad practice to write like this, because it is robust and error prone, hard to debug and maintain.

Comment: I agree here. It still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: This did work. The original line in the tutorial is: <%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

Comment: I am totally confused =) @MarekLipka

Answer (score 42):

Make sure gem 'jquery-rails' is in gemfile and jquery_ujs is included in app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: In core rails app its by default, but not when you creating an engine

Comment: +1 In my case `application.js` was missing `jquery_ujs`. I guess I have removed it while following the installation process from a twitter bootstrap gem

Comment: FYI, the plain jquery line is required as well (so you need both not just the jquery_ujs one)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue, for rails 4.2.X. Checked all my javascript files but could not make it work. if u look closely at the server request u will be missing 'authenticity_token' in the params, so user gets logged out.
In rails 4.1 and above u have to use [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) instead of link_to

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using 4.2.4 and link_to didn't work at all. How did you figure that out?

Comment: I was upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.2. It was one of the issues I faced during that upgrade process

Comment: O_O This is a great temporary hack. Has anyone figured out how to reenable the token? [I started my search here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258911/rails-4-authenticity-token)

Comment: I looked really closely at the server log posted by the OP in the question, and cannot see that error.  `link_to` works fine in Rails 4.2

Comment: Thanks a lot I spent 6 hours looking for the solution

Comment: This method deletes the post but will not confirm

Answer (score 10):

I solved the problem, just by adding in assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have a Delete REST method via rake routes.

```
DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                     articles#destroy
```

I've got the same problem only with this blog version as I'm doing both.
http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/

I'm also trying to learn how to use the web console and pry within it.
My problem is that binding.pry doesn't show up in destroy method but will in show. That tells me it must be a bad link right? It's not getting to the destroy method even. Thank you all for your answers. We do have to try things don't we?
Trying

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', { action: :destroy, id: post.id }, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

is not going to work for that one.

Here's what he has

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [comment.post, comment], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

because you only want to delete the comment here.

But combining things so far like the following gives no errors but I still have no binding.pry from the destroy method in the controller.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

and I never get the confirmation like you would expect.

So do try to figure out what's going on with the jquery as suspect.
I can confirm that was my case but the rest I'll leave for nubes because this will show up in a google search.

Answer (score 2):

`Started GET "/posts/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-09 13:45:20 -0600`

This is the problem. The delete link is using GET http verb even though you used `method: delete` in your link.

[Check out the following SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view)

Comment: Had the exact same problem and this one helped me out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

include below line in js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

include gem:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Destroy Link:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and realized that I had created my rails app with `-J` which is the same as `--skip-javascript`.
You need JavaScript enabled for this to work; the lack of a popup to confirm the delete is a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem and it was caused by triple-clicking the Guide's code block and copy/pasting the code straight into my editor (ST2 on OSX).

You should check that the generated HTML for the link looks like this:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/posts/3/comments/3" rel="nofollow">Destroy Comment</a>
```

If it doesn't, but instead looks like the below, then the Javascript won't be applied:

```
<a href="/posts/3/comments/3"                data="{:confirm=&gt;&quot;Are you sure?&quot;}"                method="delete">Destroy Comment</a>
```

The large gaps between the `href` and the unparsed Ruby are caused by the non-breaking spaces (unicode character `\u00a0`) used in the Guide being copied into your script.

I'm not sure why this doesn't cause a script parse error.

Comment: While you were at it you could have mentioned to look for the <script> lines too to be sure we have assets. But thanks Barry.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand what your comment is referring to @DouglasG.Allen?

Comment: I think it was just look at a page source in the browser but now I've forgotten. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Barry.  Make sure you're copy/pasting correctly in your /app/views/index.html.erb file and inspect the html that is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In my case, a i had change \app\views\layouts\application.html.erb file from

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to avoid my very first Rails problem. But it apparently mangled JavaScript execution and caused Destroy issue.
Therefore rollback your \app\views\layouts\application.html.erb file to its original state, and treat this problem as here

[Rails ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome)

in evedovelli answer (about coffeescript gem in windows).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I work out by this way:

My env. is:
A. ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]
B. Rails 4.2.5
C. Browser: Firfox 44.02

1. add include js in html page because delete function will use js to handle.
   `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`
2. add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`  to controller for prevent InvalidAuthenticityToken in AdsController#destroy
3. add link_to into your web page
   `<%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}%>`

   Now, I can use link_to to delete a record from my page.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `button_to` method instead of `link_to` seemed to work, minus the fact that it was not confirming(which I felt was important).

In my case, I was using react-on-rails and had multiple layouts.

Adding `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` to my hello-world layout fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my end I needed to use turbo to fix this:
`<%= link_to "Delete", company, method: :delete, data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'are you sure?' }, class:"link" %>`