# Delete path not working Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the delete method is not working when trying to destroy a record. When clicking on the button, it will redirect me to shops#show action, looks like the method: :delete is not working...Any help please?

**Routes**

```
 resources :shops
```

**HTML**

```
<% @shops.sort.each do |shop| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= shop.name %></td>
      <td><%= shop.email %></td>
      <td><%= shop.direction %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to '<button>Borrar</button>', shop, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Seguro?" } %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def destroy
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    @shop.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to "/sushiadmin", notice: 'Se ha editado la tienda.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: have you checked the same questions? maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23331608/3475678 will help.

Comment: Found an answer there, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<%= link_to 'Borrar', shop, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Seguro?" }, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

And delete Shop.find

```
def destroy
    @shop.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to "/sushiadmin", notice: 'Se ha editado la tienda.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

Comment: It will still redirect me to shops#show , strange as hell!

Comment: you just add class to the link?

Comment: Then your error is in this part: 'redirect_to "/sushiadmin' use a '_url' path instead.. You can type rake routes to find it's url link

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (specifying the `url`)

```
link_to  '<button>Borrar</button>' , shop_path( shop ), :method => 'delete', data: { confirm: "Seguro?" }
```

Acording with http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```