# ROR: Delete action only reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I believe that I have followed the tutorial completely, but when I click the "Trash It" link, the page reloads to the same `@doc` page without any change.

Have a look at the code and let me know what needs to change.

DELETE is a listed verb under the `rake routes` for `docs#destroy`.

Thanks so much for the help!

**show.html.haml:**

```
%h1= @doc.title
%p= @doc.content

= link_to "All Docs", docs_path
= link_to "Fix Docs", edit_doc_path(@doc)
= link_to "Trash It", doc_path(@doc), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you Sure?" }
```

**docs_controller.rb:**

```
class DocsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_doc, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @docs = Doc.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @doc = Doc.new
    end

    def create
        @doc = Doc.new(doc_params)

        if @doc.save
            redirect_to @doc
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @doc.update(doc_params)
            redirect_to @doc
        else 
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @doc.destroy
        redirect_to docs_path
    end

    private 

        def find_doc
            @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
        end

        def doc_params
            params.require(:doc).permit(:title, :content)
        end
end



Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :docs
end
```

Comment: Please post your routes.rb configuration for this controller.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :docs
end

Comment: in what environment are you running your app? dev/test/prod?

Comment: dev. it is running locally only.

Comment: what rails version are you on?

Comment: version: Rails 4.2.5.1

Comment: you have not defined @doc in the controller under the show action

Comment: Thanks but that isn't it either. Please reference the before action at the top of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jquery_ujs (found at https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) loaded on the page? Javascript is required to change the `<a>` to a form post with method=delete.

Comment: I do. I updated to gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1' in the gem file to make sure.

Comment: right.. but is it loaded on the page? any javascript errors? You can look at the network request in chrome debugger to figure out if it's doing a GET or a POST when clicking the link.

Comment: 3:5 GET http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/default.css 
3:6 GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/default.js

Comment: These are showing in the console tab of the debugger. Is this the information you needed? Thanks for your patience when dealing with someone who is trying to learn

Comment: You want the network tab, not the console tab. Watch to see what new requests are issued when you click the delete link.

Comment: default.css 404 stylesheet 4:5 0 B 192 ms 
default.js         404 script         4:6 0 B 362 ms                                       These show in red

Answer (score 0):

Make sure gem 'jquery-rails' is in gemfile and jquery_ujs is included in app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I believe your problem is similar [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154916/rails-4-link-to-destroy-not-working-in-getting-started-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, this is not the issue as the above described are already present.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help! I was able to figure out the source of the problem.

I had changed 'application' to 'default' in the application.html.erb on lines 5 and 6 to fix a Rails ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home? error that has is common on Windows machines.

For reference, the fix was to install a prev version of the  gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'. After changing back the application.html.erb file, I am now in business!

Thanks again for all who helped!