# link_to destroy action results in get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a link to delete a Project...

```
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <h2><%= project.name %> (<%= project.videos.size %>)</h2> 
      <%= link_to("Delete!", {:controller=>'projects', :action=>'destroy', :id=>project.hashed_id}, {method: :delete} ) %>
  <% end %>
```

No matter what I do I get a `get` request so I end up on the projects/show view. Urrrgh!

My controller:

```
  def destroy
    @project = Project.where( :hashed_id=> params[:id]).first.destroy()
    flash[:notice]= "Project deleted"
    redirect_to(:action=>'index')
  end
```

What am I missing?

PS: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574370/issue-in-rails-4-0-with-creating-a-link-to-for-a-delete-action), but the solution doesn't work for me.

**Update**

```
$ rake routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            pages#home
    projects GET    /projects(.:format)          projects#index
             POST   /projects(.:format)          projects#create
 new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
     project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
             PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
             PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
             DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
```

**Update 2**
Here's the error I get:

[image]

Comment: What HTML is rendered for the link_to?

Comment: Did you try `link_to("Delete!", project_path(project), action: :delete)`

Comment: do you have a public repo where we can see the code?

Comment: @Ben Not yet. It's all local at the moment,

Comment: OK, no problem. The NoMethodError you're getting is because `@project` is nil. That means, the first place to check is your `show` action does return a non-nil `@project`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste your output of `rake routes`. I suspect that the routes are not matching, that's why it falls to `#show` instead.

Make sure you have jquery-rails installed too.

See [Delete / Destroy is not working in rails 3 with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784633/delete-destroy-is-not-working-in-rails-3-with-jquery).

In general, make sure that you have included all the necessary javascript files.

Comment: Just added it to the question above.

Comment: Why is my problem connected to JavaScript? (Im a rails n00b)

Comment: Also what's the best way to check?

Comment: It has to do with unobstrusive javascript. The best way to check is to paste your `Gemfile` and `application.js` and also to make sure you are including the js.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is uour hashed_id for? You usually should be able to do something like link_to(project, method: :delete). or link_to(project_path(project), method: :delete)

Comment: I'm using a hashed ID which comes from a 3rd party API that I'm integrating with. Id rather show only the hashed_id to the client.

Comment: @BenjaminTan it WAS a JavaScript issue. I had commented our the application.js tag because the file was empty, but evidently that does more than I realized because when I uncommented it, the delete request works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

Controller:

```
def destroy
  Flower.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

Views:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', flower_path(flower), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: Hi Sami, I tried it with project_path(project) instead of the :action/:controller syntax and I *STILL* get a get request.

Comment: can you show your error message, latest controller's destroy method and the link to tag.

Comment: Error message added above.

Comment: it could not find name in your projects

Comment: It could not find name because it's rendering the show view but the controller failed to pass a project object

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', project_path(project), method: :delete %>
```

It should work.
If doesn't, paste the server log in comments or try to check your generated path.

Or check at your rails c:

```
app.project_path(Project.first)
```

Good luck!